# Word disappearing text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently setting up some MS Word templates in Word 2010 and have encountered a problem, where text suddenly disappears at the end of a paragraph.

The problem only occurs in some specific scenarios, but I have experienced that it can be recreated in a lot of different ways. I have not, however, been able to pinpoint the exact reason why this happens. Therefore, I would like to find the specific reason, that makes the issue occur, in order to avoid it.

It seems that a combination of the existence of wrapped tables, content in the page header and a certain length of a line can invoke the issue.

To recreate a document where this issue occurs, please follow this procedure:

1. Open a new document in Word 2010.
2. Copy the code below into a new module in the VBA editor.
3. Run the `A_ReplicateScenario` macro to insert example content in the document.
4. Place the cursor at the end of line 3 (the line that ends close to the margin).
5. Type a new sentence after the dot, beginning with a space.

The text that you have typed, will disappear when the margin is reached.

*The text will then be shown if for instance a character is deleted from the original text (i.e. from the beginning of the line) or if a formatting change is made (e.g. clear formatting). The 'Show all' setting in Word can also sometimes display the text, but will only display it while 'Show all' is activated. Other times Word will display 'ghosted' double lines which can not be selected.*

A short video of the replicated issue can be viewed here: https://youtu.be/Bqp9STDRkXc

```
Sub A_ReplicateScenario()

    Call SetUpNormalStyle
    Call InsertBodyTextLines
    Call InsertHeaderTextLines
    Call InsertWrappedTables
    Call SetUpMargins
    Call InsertExampleBodyText

End Sub

Sub SetUpNormalStyle()

    With ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
    End With
    With ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").ParagraphFormat
        .SpaceAfter = 0
        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast
        .LineSpacing = 12
    End With

End Sub

Sub InsertBodyTextLines()

    For i = 1 To 4
        Selection.TypeParagraph
    Next

End Sub

Sub InsertHeaderTextLines()

    If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
    End If
    If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
        ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If

    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader

    For i = 1 To 26
        Selection.TypeParagraph
    Next

    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument

End Sub

Sub InsertWrappedTables()

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
    With Selection.Tables(1).Rows
        .WrapAroundText = True
        .HorizontalPosition = CentimetersToPoints(2)
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
        .VerticalPosition = CentimetersToPoints(4.5)
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
    End With
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).PreferredWidth = CentimetersToPoints(11)

    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
    With Selection.Tables(1).Rows
        .WrapAroundText = True
        .HorizontalPosition = CentimetersToPoints(10)
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
        .VerticalPosition = CentimetersToPoints(8)
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
    End With
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).PreferredWidth = CentimetersToPoints(9)

End Sub

Sub SetUpMargins()

    With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
        .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(3.8)
        .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.8)
        .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.3)
        .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    End With

End Sub

Sub InsertExampleBodyText()

    With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        .MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=3

        .TypeText Text:="Ouwouwouwoiwoiuwoiuwoiuwoiuwoiuwoiuwoiw oiwu oiwu owiu woiu woiuw oiwu owiu owiu ww."
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:="Woiuwoiuwoiuw."
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried to test the same replicated scenario in Word 2007 and 2013, but cannot trigger the issue here. So it seems to be a Word 2010 only issue.

Comment: These are one of the best repro-steps I've seen here on SO. Great! I was able to repro this in Word 2013 as well but the problem went away when I was starting Word in safe mode (simply hold Ctrl while starting Word). Safe mode did not seem to have any effect in Word 2010 though. This looks certainly like a bug in Office so there is probably not much you could about it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the tables being formatted to float around the text. Word has a long history of issues with floating objects. And although Word has improved a lot over the years you might still experience problems, in particular with floating tables.

If you change the formatting of the second table (via *Table Properties*) and set the text wrapping to *None*, the bug goes away (YMMV).

My recommendation would be to avoid the floating tables if possible.

Comment: Moving the tables to the header or footer can sometimes help too - though this isn't always an option, depending on the document content etc.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. It does indeed match my experiences with the issue, that the floating tables have an important role. However, it is weird that the problem only occurs in collation with a defined Normal style. If the call to 'SetUpNormalStyle' is skipped in the replication macro, the problem goes away. It is not likely that you will have a document with no defined normal style, though.